# Error #1064 when declaring a variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to declare and manipulate a variable in MySQL like this:

```
DECLARE @tim;
//find the difference between current time and time at which the data was stored in the database
SET @tim=(select TIMEDIFF(NOW(),E.reg_date)
      FROM `mytable2` E)
```

But I get the following error:

> error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DECLARE @tim' at line 1

What is causing this error and how can I avoid it? The MySQL server version is 5.6.17.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, your syntax is wrong.

### tl;dr: `SET` the variable, do not `DECLARE` it.

`DECLARE` is only used when working with variables in routines such as stored procedures, functions and triggers. See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.

You are trying to [set a user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) outside of a routine:

> One way to set a user-defined variable is by issuing a SET statement:
>
> ```
> SET @var_name = expr [, @var_name = expr] ...
> ```

Everything you need to know about this statement, including quite a bit of information about setting session and global variables, is in [the documentation for `SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
select TIMEDIFF(NOW(),E.reg_date) into @tim FROM mytable2 E
```

Comment: after doing this query i queried:select @tim it showed null

Comment: That will happen is E has more than 1 row.

Comment: Also if you are not in a being and end block, then just remove the "Declare @tim" altogether.  It will be created when you run the query.